# CPToolbar renders in the CPBorderlessBridgeWindowMask window only

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I tried to add the custom toolbar to my application. To locate it at the bottom of the window I created one more window and added the toolbar to it:

```
var theWindow = [[CPWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:CGRectMakeZero() styleMask:CPBorderlessBridgeWindowMask],
    contentView = [theWindow contentView],
    bounds = [contentView bounds];
[contentView setBackgroundColor:[CPColor colorWithHexString:@"cecece"]];

///second window to place the toolbar at the bottom
var w2 = [[CPPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(bounds) - _settings.toolbarSize,
                                                          CGRectGetWidth(bounds), _settings.toolbarSize)
                           styleMask: CPBorderlessWindowMask]
var c2 = [w2 contentView]
[c2 setBackgroundColor:[CPColor colorWithHexString:@"ff0000"]];

///a toolbar
toolbar = [[Toolbar alloc] initWithWindow:w2];

///show window
[theWindow orderFront:self];
[w2 orderFront:self];
```

It worked properly with the Cappuccino 0.8.1 but does not with the latest one. Only if I either set toolbar for `theWindow` or init `w2` with `CPBorderlessBridgeWindowMask` it renders as needed.

Does anyone have any idea what is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Not sure what you have in your `Toolbar` subclass. Did you try just `var toolbar = [CPToolbar new]; [w2 setToolbar:toolbar];`?

Comment: I did. The result was the same.

Comment: `CPBorderlessWindowMask` should be fine. What is the result of sending `[toolbar _toolbarViewFrame]`? What about `[w2._windowView showsToolbar]`? If you make the window larger than you need, do you see a toolbar then?